# how to make a binding variable's value to a host(define) variable?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
variable dbid number;

select dbid into :dbid from dba_hist_snapshot;
```

then if I want the `:dbid` can be as a value to a host variable, eg:

```
define dbid_1=:dbid;
```

how to make it?

Actually I just want to exec @@?/rdbms/admin/awrsqrpt.sql; without interactive command line.

Comment: Are you using sqlplus?

Comment: yes, sqlplus, actually i just want to exec @@?/rdbms/admin/awrsqrpt.sql; without interactive command line

Answer (score 0):

This shows how to run a report.  The *sqlplus variables* (not bind variables) are preceded by an ampersand and can be set by using the COLUMN statement with a NEW_VALUE or OLD_VALUE option. More can be found in the [Oracle SQL*Plus User's Guide and Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQPUG/ch_twelve013.htm#SQPUG034)

```
rem check ?/rdbms/admin/awrrpt.sql
rem and check ?/rdbms/admin/awrrpti.sql
rem we want not display a list of snap_ids
define num_days = 0;
rem we want to create a report of type text
define report_type='text';

rem choose the dbid of the current instance
column dbid old_value dbid;
select dbid from v$database;

rem choose the instance_number of the current instance for inst_num
column INSTANCE_NUMBER old_value inst_num
select INSTANCE_NUMBER from v$instance;


rem choose the last snap_id as END_SNAP
column end_snap new_value end_snap
select max(snap_id) end_snap
      from DBA_HIST_SNAPSHOT
  where DBID=&DBID
  and INSTANCE_NUMBER=&INST_NUM
/

rem choose the snap_id before the last snap_id as BEGIN_SNAP
column begin_snap new_value begin_snap
select max(snap_id) begin_snap
      from DBA_HIST_SNAPSHOT
  where DBID=&DBID
  and snap_id < &end_snap
  and INSTANCE_NUMBER=&INST_NUM
/

rem the following ways to define report_name do not work
rem because of leading blanks in the variables
rem define report_name=awr_&BEGIN_SNAP._&END_SNAP..txt
rem define report_name="awr_&BEGIN_SNAP._&END_SNAP..txt"

REM set the report name
column report_name old_value report_name
select 'awr_'||trim('&BEGIN_SNAP')||'_'||
  trim('&END_SNAP')||'.txt' report_name
from dual;

promp report_name &report_name
@?/rdbms/admin/awrrpt.sql

exit
```

Comment: thanks, while I get "dbms_workload_repository.awr_sql_report_html"  to instead of the awrrpt.sql/ awrrpti.sql

Answer (score 0):

```
-- get dbid, inst_num, bid, eid, sql_id for awr report
var dbid number;
var inst_num number;
var bid number;
var eid number;
var sql_id varchar2(20);
begin
    select dbid into :dbid from v$database;
    select instance_number into :inst_num from v$instance;
    select min(snap_id) into :bid from dba_hist_snapshot;
    select max(snap_id) into :eid from dba_hist_snapshot;
    :sql_id := 'xxxxx';
end;
/

-- create awr for SQL ID: 1swzr1yyxu1q0 to save at '/tmp', report name awr_.html
CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY awr_reports_dir AS '/tmp'; 
--'&1'
declare
l_dir varchar2(50) := 'AWR_REPORTS_DIR';
l_file UTL_FILE.file_type;
l_file_name varchar(50);
begin
    l_file := utl_file.fopen (l_dir, 'awr_'||:sql_id||'.html', 'w', 32767);
    for cur_rep in (select output from table(dbms_workload_repository.awr_sql_report_html(:dbid, :inst_num,:bid,:eid, :sql_id,0 )))
    loop
        utl_file.put_line(l_file, cur_rep.output);
    end loop;
    utl_file.fclose(l_file);
end;
/
```